# Ctrl + n launches new windows. How to disable

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, awesome

Having to pass a coding test soon, I am going to use an browser-embedded IDE. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and awesome wm. When I press Ctrl + n in the active IDE, a new browser window is launched for some reason. the keybinding is neither used by awesome, nor by ubuntu or by chrome. Firefox shows the same behavior and so does e.g. Nautilus. Upon hitting ctrl+n a new instance is launched. I would like for this to be disabled so that it no longer shadows the behaviour in the web IDE. Can someone tell me how to change it or where the problem lies?

Comment: My Firefox browser shows in its File menu "New Window Ctrl+N" . My Chromium browser shows in the 3 vertical-dots menu ... "New Window Ctrl+N". As I don't see firefox or chrome tags in your question I'm not sure you're aware of this. This is a feature from the browser, the answer would be browser-specific if any.  Here's a random SO example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838302/any-way-to-override-ctrln-to-open-a-new-window-in-chrome

Comment: and the equivalent hardening in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1291706

Comment: but as I said, the same behavior occurs for my file explorer at this key combo

Comment: So? Does it invalidate what I wrote?